# How can I bind a form parameter to a Java 8 Duration using Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsr310

I know I can bind a Spring MVC form bean to a LocalDateTime using:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
private LocalDateTime startTime;
```

This will convert a String like `2016-01-11T15:05:05.123Z` to a `LocalDateTime` object.

I have found some docs on this here: http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/06/spring-4-datetimeformat-with-java-8.html

I could not find how to do the same with `java.time.Duration`. How do I do this?

Comment: `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)` isn't mandatory

Comment: Make sure you spelled the duration correctly - `PT1D` is invalid, should be `P1D`. Hours and smaller need `PT`. And you can combine with `P1DT1H`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems nothing is needed. It works out of the box (Using Spring Boot 1.3.1 with Spring 4.2.4) with Duration and ZoneId:

```
private Duration duration;
private ZoneId timeZone;
```

I tested with "PT15H" string for duration and "Europe/Brussels" for timeZone.